# how to save data from webcrawlling by date, mealtype

Tags: swift, web-crawler, string-formatting, swiftsoup

As you can see in this screenshot, I want to save those Korean-written data in array. (actually they are food menu of my dormitory)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-center table-data">
            <colgroup>
                <col width="18%">
                <col width="28%">
                <col width="28%">
                <col width="28%">
            </colgroup>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>구 분</th>
                    <th>조 식</th>
                    <th>중 식</th>
                    <th>석 식</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr style="height:80px">
                        <th>
                            2021년 09월 13일 (월요일)</th>
                        <td>와플/생크림,쨈,감자소시지크림스튜,양배추콘샐럳,</td>
                        <td>발아현미밥,짜박이된장찌개,치즈불닭,명란오이무침,김치</td>
                        <td>렌즈콩밥,풋팟퐁커리,콩나물국,얌운센샐러드,단무지채무침,김치</td>
                    </tr>
                <tr style="height:80px">
                        <th>
                            2021년 09월 14일 (화요일)</th>
                        <td>소고기맑은장국,마약메추리알,진미채볶음,김치</td>
                        <td>흑미밥,목살고추장찌개,임연수구이,우엉호두강정,김치</td>
                        <td>찰수수밥,청국장김치찌개,돈육갈비찜,미나리버섯초무침,백김치</td>
                    </tr>
                <tr style="height:80px">
                        <th>
                            2021년 09월 15일 (수요일)</th>
                        <td>새우미역죽,동그랑땡,꼴뚜기젓무침,김치볶음,쥬스</td>
                        <td>얼큰잔치국수,멸치주먹밥,회오리감자,참나물생채,김치</td>
                        <td>율무밥,옹심이만두전골,녹두전/오징어장떡,시금치나물,김치</td>
                    </tr>
                <tr style="height:80px">
                        <th>
                            2021년 09월 16일 (목요일)</th>
                        <td>또띠아에그콘피자,우유,초코첵스,오렌지</td>
                        <td>중국식볶음밥,유부팽이장국,로제떡볶이,마늘장아찌,김치</td>
                        <td>혼합잡곡밥,콩나물국,간장소스파닭,무피클,고추된장무침,김치</td>
                    </tr>
                <tr style="height:80px">
                        <th>
                            2021년 09월 17일 (금요일)</th>
                        <td>황태맑은국,어묵죽순볶음,건파래볶음,김치</td>
                        <td>낙지콩나물비빔밥,토란맑은국,김치,모둠과일</td>
                        <td>기장밥,대구매운탕,두부감자강정,마늘쫑베이컨무침,김치</td>
                    </tr>
                <tr style="height:80px">
                        <th>
                            2021년 09월 18일 (토요일)</th>
                        <td>누룽지죽,햄전,쑥갓나물,김치볶음</td>
                        <td>차조밥,아욱국,돈육불고기,양배추&amp;깻잎쌈,무생채,김치</td>
                        <td>간편식</td>
                    </tr>
                <tr style="height:80px">
                        <th style="color:red;">
                            2021년 09월 19일 (일요일)</th>
                        <td>간편식</td>
                        <td>간편식</td>
                        <td>간편식</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
        </table>
    </div><!-- // table-responsive -->
</div>
```

With codes below, I could get only entire data like

```
let html = try String(contentsOf: myURL, encoding: .utf8)
let doc: Document = try SwiftSoup.parse(html)
let body = try doc.body()
let menu = try body?.getElementsByClass("table-responsive").text()
```

[image]

<Don't care the Korean, they are just food menu....>

but I want to save them separated by date and meal type.

As I'm new to swift soup and web crawling, I'm very confusing now.

Is there any way to save them seperately in array?